# Template loading locations

Tags: django

i am newbie to django and learning by doing small application.
in views.py i have intentionally included a template file(.html) which does not exist.

```
t = get_template('current_datetimeP.html')
```

in setting.py 
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    "D:/Django_Code/mysite/templates/",
)

i get this error **TemplateDoesNotExist** at /time/

Django tried loading these templates, in this order:
Using loader django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader:
   **D:\Django_Code\mysite\templates\current_datetimeP.html (File does not exist)**

since i have included D:\Django_Code\mysite\templates\ in settings.py its fine that the Django is loking in there but what about following

I also get this

Using loader django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader:
    **C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\templates\current_datetimeP.html (File does not exist)**

**Why** Django looking in here  **C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\templates**. 
Is it a default location to search templates ?

one more thing , its is evident that Django is looking in above directory. can we place templates file in there instead of putting in application directory. (Although it is not a good practice ) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Template loading is controlled by the TEMPLATE_LOADERS setting in settings.py, which usually looks something like this:

```
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
)
```

The app directories loader looks for templates in a "templates" folder in any of the apps listed in INSTALLED_APPS in settings.

The filesystem loader attempts to load templates from the fully qualified directory path names listed under TEMPLATE_DIRS in the settings file.

If you wish to give the filesystem loader preference, let it come before the app directories loader in the TEMPLATE_LOADERS setting. If you'd like to turn off app directories loading, comment it out with a # ( or delete it from the tuple ).

Comment: ok. but why it has stopped at auth ? there are other applications also installed like 'django.contrib.contenttypes', django.contrib.sessions, etc. why it is nt looking in these ?

Comment: It goes through the installed applications in the order in which they are defined in INSTALLED_APPS. Could you check and see if auth comes after django.contrib.contenttypes or vice-versa?

Comment: my point is if it is not find in place A , then shouldn't it be looking in place B, place C etc

Comment: Some of the apps, for example sessions, and contenttypes, do not include template folders. I believe the list of app template directories is cached when the django application starts, so these apps are not checked on subsequent requests.

Answer (score 0):

try using template path created with settings.py location

```
import os
DIRNAME = os.path.dirname(__file__)
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(DIRNAME, "templates"),
)


TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
'django.template.loaders.filesystem.load_template_source',
'django.template.loaders.app_directories.load_template_source',
)
```

Comment: D:\Django_Code\mysite\templates\mytemp.html (windows). DIRNAME = ?

Comment: TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/django_templates".
    # `Always use forward slashes, even on Windows`.
    os.path.join(DIRNAME, "templates"),
)